# GitHub pages failing to load resource and giving 404 error, but it loads fine when running locally

Tags: html, github-pages

The Github pages site published at: https://mia-ktlk.github.io/photography-demo/ is **failing to load resources** imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js, and masonry.pkgd.min.js. If I try to find their corresponding urls I see 404 errors at each:

- https://mia-ktlk.github.io/photography-demo/vendor/mdb/js/addons/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js
- https://mia-ktlk.github.io/photography-demo/vendor/mdb/js/addons/masonry.pkgd.min.js

However, the files are there in the repo you can see them here.

- https://github.com/mia-ktlk/photography-demo/blob/master/vendor/MDB/js/addons/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js
- https://github.com/mia-ktlk/photography-demo/blob/master/vendor/MDB/js/addons/masonry.pkgd.min.js

Everything loads fine locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

githhub pages is case sensitive I changed:

to